# Image ignore max-width on load, but accepts it after toggling the max-width, or resizing the window

Tags: html, css

I have some divs and an image inside, and the css is working as I want it (almost), except that when I refresh the page or load it for the first time, the image width takes the entire div width, which ignores the css properties. It only notices the css properties when the window is resized (e.g. by 1px), or if in google developer tools, I toggle the max-width off and then back on, or if I toggle the parent div display off and then back on.

You can see this is the case in this video I just took:
https://youtu.be/YLx4NjKuzMo

Bear in mind, this issue occurs after about 880px width.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}
header {
  height: 15vh;
  min-height: 80px;
  background-color: #262626;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3vw;
  color: #f60;
}
ul {
  line-height: 3.5vw;
}
.white-text {
  color: #fff;
}
.orange-text {
  color: #f60;
}
.page-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  min-height: 460px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 2vw;
  position: relative;
}
#logo {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 3vh;
}
.landing-section {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 4vw;
  padding-top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
#employees {
  background-color: #fff;
}
#employers {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.values-list {
  margin-left: 7vw;
  margin-top: 2vw;
}
.rounded {
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.div-call-to-action {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.landing-icon {
  width: 15vw;
  height: 15vw;
}
.p-see-how {
  margin: auto 0;
  color: #f60;
}
.arrow-icon {
  margin: auto 1.5vw;
  min-width: 45px;
  min-height: 45px;
  width: 4vw;
  height: 4vw;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: #f60 /*in case image doesn't load*/;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.arrow-icon:active {
  background-color: #fff /*in case image doesn't load*/;
  border: 1px solid #f60;
}
.is-flex {
  display: flex;
}
/*@media (max-width: 1000px) and (max-height: 1000px)
 #logo
  width 320px
  height initial
  padding 0*/
#img-screen-chat-top-parent {
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 2.5%;
}
#img-screen-chat-btm-parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#img-screen-chat {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <img id="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="ratedby">
        </header>
        <section class="page-container">
            <section class="landing-section" id="employees">
                <div class="div-why">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                    <ul class="values-list">
                        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="div-call-to-action">
                    <img class="rounded landing-icon" id="chef-icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Looking for work?">
                    <div class="is-flex">
                        <p class="p-see-how">Lorem</p>
                        <div class="arrow-icon" id="arrow-employees"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section id="img-screen-chat-top-parent">
                <div id="img-screen-chat-btm-parent">
                    <img id="img-screen-chat" alt="Mobile app screen" src="http://via.placeholder.com/729x1530">
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="landing-section" id="employers">
                <div class="div-why">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                    <ul class="values-list">
                        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="div-call-to-action">
                    <img class="rounded landing-icon" id="hire-icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Looking for work?">
                    <div class="is-flex">
                        <p class="p-see-how">Lorem</p>
                        <div class="arrow-icon" id="arrow-employers"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </section>
```

Comment: It'd be appreciated if you add the code.

Comment: ok give me a minute

Comment: Bear in mind, this issue occurs after about 880px screen width, and is difficult/impossible to replicate in the code snippet above since it is not on page load.

Comment: I just decided to go with background-image css instead of this img malarkey